# Get all merkle trees created by an account

Tags: compression

I have created numerous trees but I cannot find them.

How to retrieve an array of all the trees?

Using Solana web3 js

Answer (score 1):

Helius has a transaction history API.

https://docs.helius.dev/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history

You can run it on your wallet. It will be a little tricky to extract which tree creations but it is doable.

Alternatively perhaps you could run a GPA on the bubblegum program and filter for tree config accounts.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/blob/main/programs/bubblegum/program/src/state/mod.rs#L17

Where you are the tree creator. If you used Bubblegum.